# Editable fields inside aggrid table are moving out of table while scrolling [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag-grid table in angular and I am trying to edit the date column which is custom and I used the following config:

```
...(column.id === "date" && {
    cellEditor: customDateEditor,
    editable: true,
    cellEditorPopup: true
   })
```

and in my customDateEditor component , the code is :

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" [showIcon]="true" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
```

Here, Iam using primeng datepicker to open when i click on date column cell in the table. This is working as expected.

Issue is when i open the datepicker and start scrolling top or bottom , the  field is moving out of the ag-grid table.

How can I keep the field fixed at the position it opened even after scroll? or how to close the date-picker on scroll, something like invoking `params.api.stopEditing()` , (to perform this , i am not able to find any event that gets triggered on table scroll).

I tried using css properties to fix the position , but didnt work. I also tried giving appendTo="table-id" , but the calendar popup is hiding under the table when opened.

I have tried reading the documentation to find if there is any configuration for this similar to `popupParent` , but no luck.

The ag-grid version iam using is :

```
"ag-grid-angular": "29.1.0",
"ag-grid-community": "29.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "29.1.0",
```

Any suggestions or help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try without `appendTo="body"`

Comment: Hi @Rober, I already tried it by removing appendTo=body, This also has the same issue both the calendar input field and the pop-up moves together out of table.

Comment: Can you create a [Stackblitz](http://www.stackblitz.com) about this issue?